# Centering the headings in a table without expanding the table over one column

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, formatting

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{The output of the cross-validation used for the hyperparameters optimization}
\label{table:hyper} 
\begin{tabular}{ p{2.2cm} p{3.5cm} p{2cm} }
  \toprule
    Hyperparameters           & \textbf{Values}                  & \textbf{Selected Values}       \\ 
  \midrule
    N\underline {o} of layers & 2,3,4,5,6,7,8                    & 2 – both encoding and decoding \\
    Neurons in each laye      & 80,70,60,50,45,40,30,25,20,15,10 & 70,50,30                       \\
    Dimensions for coding     & 80,70,60,50,45,40,30,25,20,15,10 & 45,25                          \\
    Sparsity                  & 10e-5,10e-3,10e-1                & 10e-5                          \\
    Activation function       & Relu, Sigmoid                    & Relu, Sigmoid                  \\
    Optimizer                 & Default                          & adadelta                       \\ 
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.stackexchange. May I suggest that you turn your code into a compilable minimal working example with a preamble using all of the required packages (I see you probably use e.g. `booktabs` ) That way, it is easier for others to help you. Also I am not sure, your question is very clear, can you maybe add more specifics about what it is that you are trying to achieve, possibly with a sketch?

Answer (score 2):

For a limited scope (here, inside the table) I make the comma active and define it as

```
\def,{\char`,\allowbreak}
```

thus, allowing it to permit breaks.  I also slightly widen the left column and make columns 1 and 3 `\raggedright`, as well.  Finally, I add a bit of `\arraystretch` to separate the rows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{The output of the cross-validation used for the hyperparameters optimization}
\label{table:hyper} 
\catcode`,=\active
\def,{\char`,\allowbreak}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{p{2.4cm}<{\raggedright} p{3.5cm} p{2cm}<{\raggedright} }
  \toprule
    Hyperparameters           & \textbf{Values}                  & \textbf{Selected Values}       \\ 
  \midrule
    N\underline {o} of layers & 2,3,4,5,6,7,8                    & 2 – both encoding and decoding \\
    Neurons in each layer      & 80,70,60,50,45,40,30,25,20,15,10 & 70,50,30                       \\
    Dimensions for coding     & 80,70,60,50,45,40,30,25,20,15,10 & 45,25                          \\
    Sparsity                  & 10e-5,10e-3,10e-1                & 10e-5                          \\
    Activation function       & Relu, Sigmoid                    & Relu, Sigmoid                  \\
    Optimizer                 & Default                          & adadelta                       \\ 
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]